# Count values checking if consecutive

Tags: sql, postgresql-10

This is my table:

```
Event       Order               Timestamp
delFailed   281475031393706     2018-07-24T15:48:08.000Z
reopen      281475031393706     2018-07-24T15:54:36.000Z
reopen      281475031393706     2018-07-24T15:54:51.000Z
```

I need to count the number of event 'delFailed' and 'reopen' to calculate `#delFailed - #reopen`.
The difficulty is that there cannot be two same consecutives events, so that in this case the result will be "0" not "-1".

This is what i have achieved so far (Which is wrong because it gives me -1 instead of 0 due to the fact there are two consecutive "reopen" events )

```
with 
    events as (
        select 
            event as events,
            orders,
            "timestamp"
        from main_source_execevent
        where orders = '281475031393706'
        and event in ('reopen', 'delFailed')
        order by "timestamp"
    ),
    count_events as (
        select 
            count(events) as CEvents,
            events,
            orders
        from events
        group by orders, events
    )
select (
    (select cevents from count_events where events = 'delFailed') - (select cevents from count_events where events = 'reopen')
) as nAttempts,
orders
from count_events
group by orders
```

How can i count once if there are two same consecutive events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a gaps-and-islands problem, you can use make to row number to check rows are two same consecutive events

**Explain**

1. one row number created by normal.
2. another row number created by `Event` column

---

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp) grp
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Event ORDER BY Timestamp) rn
    FROM T
  ) t1


|     event |           Order |            timestamp | grp | rn |
|-----------|-----------------|----------------------|-----|----|
| delFailed | 281475031393706 | 2018-07-24T15:48:08Z |   1 |  1 |
|    reopen | 281475031393706 | 2018-07-24T15:54:36Z |   2 |  1 |
|    reopen | 281475031393706 | 2018-07-24T15:54:51Z |   3 |  2 |
```

when you create those two row you can get an upper result, then use `grp - rn` to get calculation the row are or are not same consecutive.

```
 SELECT *,grp-rn
  FROM (
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp) grp
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Event ORDER BY Timestamp) rn
    FROM T
  ) t1

|     event |           Order |            timestamp | grp | rn |   grp-rn |
|-----------|-----------------|----------------------|-----|----|----------|
| delFailed | 281475031393706 | 2018-07-24T15:48:08Z |   1 |  1 |        0 |
|    reopen | 281475031393706 | 2018-07-24T15:54:36Z |   2 |  1 |        1 |
|    reopen | 281475031393706 | 2018-07-24T15:54:51Z |   3 |  2 |        1 |
```

you can see when if there are two same consecutive events `grp-rn` column will be the same, so we can `group by` by  `grp-rn` column and get `count`

Final query.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Event VARCHAR(50),
  "Order"  VARCHAR(50),
  Timestamp Timestamp
); 

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('delFailed',281475031393706,'2018-07-24T15:48:08.000Z');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('reopen',281475031393706,'2018-07-24T15:54:36.000Z');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('reopen',281475031393706,'2018-07-24T15:54:51.000Z');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN  event = 'delFailed' THEN 1 END) -  
    SUM(CASE WHEN  event = 'reopen' THEN 1 END) result
FROM (
  SELECT Event,COUNT(distinct Event)
  FROM (
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp) grp
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Event ORDER BY Timestamp) rn
    FROM T
  ) t1
  group by grp - rn,Event
)t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d9058/3/0)**:

```
| result |
|--------|
|      0 |
```

Comment: Thank you this solution fits perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `lag()` to get the first event in any sequence of similar values.  Then do the calculation:

```
select sum( (event = 'reopen')::int ) as num_reopens,
       sum( (event = 'delFailed')::int ) as num_delFailed
from (select mse.*,
             lag(event) over (partition by orders order by "timestamp") as prev_event
      from main_source_execevent mse
      where orders = '281475031393706' and
            event in ('reopen', 'delFailed')
     ) e
where prev_event <> event or prev_event is null;
```